# import a library into my project

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-library

I made a project and I want to use the [slideMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library but when I import it the package.R class will be undefined because the attr.xml that found in library res/values. like `import offers.findme.com.R;`

Comment: You should refer your library project in your android project.

1. import library project into your workspace and into eclipse.

2.  Right click on your android project. goto properties. Choose android. Click add browse the library project and add the same.

Now clean and build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a invalid line in style.xml that prevent me to access the new library the line was id property

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...
Once you download the file from site you mentioned and extract it to a given destination, all you have to do (if you're using Eclipse) is

- **File-->import-->Android-->Existing Android into Workspace** , and select that
  library location.
- And  to use it in your projects go to
  **properties>Android and add the new library**.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I added the library but after adding it the Project.R is not defined don't know why but when I delete the res/values/attr.xml there is no error found but I can't use the attribute

Comment: Have you tried clean and build your project ANd then  --> right click your project>Android tools>Fix project Properties and then clean build again... Also try restarting eclipse ...

Comment: @CRUSADER my dear i have gallery app and i download image zoom library and i imported to my project how can i use it inside my gallery class to apply the zoom effect, thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

if you use eclipse then start a new project say projectLib from library source

and then configure the build path of the project to include the projectLib and rember to export i with the app

alternatively you could copy the source and resources of your library to your project and instead of offers.findme.com.R look up for your.project.R

Comment: Did you copy the whole library in the project? Do that without eclipse and don't overwrite any files you must add the values manually to those then the library resources will be generated in your project's R and u can access them from there

Comment: I did it but when I add the res/values/attr.xml the R is not reading

Answer (score 0):

You should refer your library project in your android project.

1. import library project into your workspace and into eclipse.
2. Right click on your android project. goto properties. Choose android. Click add browse the library project and add the same.

Now clean and build.

For more info check the link below. The link has snap shots if you scroll down

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

First you need to import the library as an Android Project.

Then you need to set it as your project's library, by Right-Click your project directory > Properties

There you can mark the library project as your project's library.

After that, Project > Clean your project.

The [README](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/README.md) file says the steps clearly.

Regards.

Comment: but after doing those steps the myproject.R is undefined I think it from the res/values/attr.xml cause when I delete it there is no error show but it will make an exception when I run it.

Comment: Did you clean the project after adding it as a library? If you clean a new R.java will be generated. It should be working then.

Comment: I checked the res/values/attr.xml I see nothing wrong with it. sometimes these error occurs when you are referencing a different R.java. See where is your R.java, it should be in gen folder. then see in the imports it should be something like com.your.projectname.R

Comment: The project can't generate the R.java file don't know why

Comment: I just tried it in my eclipse. Worked fine. Are you using some other library also? There is a section in README that says if you are using SherlockActionBar you need to do something different.